# Finding the Cumulative distribution(CDF)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose there is a unit disk where $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ and a point is chosen randomly in that region. Knowing the radius is related to the variables $x$ and $y$ how can I find the CDF/PDF of the random variable $R$ given that the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is $\text{uniform}(1/\pi)$?
Here what I attempted but got stuck on:

Since I know $R^2 = X^2 + Y^2$  and that the range of $r$ is $[0,1]$, therefore the  cdf at $Fr(0)=0$ and $Fr(1)=0$. In between this range, $$FR(r)=P(R\le r) = P((X^2+Y^2) \le r).$$
I know the next step is to integrate the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$, but how do I go about knowing $P((X^2+Y^2)\le r)$ to find the cdf?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $r \in [0,1]$, the $P[R \le r]$ is the area of the points inside the
circle of radius $r$ divided by the total area. Hence
$P[R \le r] = {\pi r^2 \over \pi}= r^2$.